# Passing in a form name in context to Redux Form formValueSelector using a render props function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Reusing the same Redux Form, I need to access the value of a field within the form for the current context. Going by the docs, I should use the [FormName](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formname.md/) render props component, which does render the name of the current form e.g:

```
<FormName>{({ form }) => <span>Form name in context is: {form}</span>}</FormName>;
```

Is it possible to dynamically pass in the form name to FormValueSelector through the use of FormName?

```
const description = formValueSelector("CREATION_FORM")(state, "description");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just passed the form name as a prop and accessed it in ownProps.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  description: formValueSelector(ownProps.form)(state, "description"),
});
```